# angularjs Button gets de-selected in IE11 but works in chrome and firefox

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11

Sorry I am new to this arena , I have below code which is not working in `IE11` but works in `Chrome` and `Firefox`.

```
<div class="btn-group-sm">
<button type="button" class="someCssclassName{{dummyclass.textProp}} btn btn-primary btn-square" ng-model="dummyclass.prop2" uib-btn-radio="item" uncheckable="uncheckable" ng-repeat="item in dummyClass.items | filter: { SomeProperty : 11 }">
</button>
<div>
```

In above code if I remove `someCssclassName{{dummyclass.textProp}}` , it works fine.

Comment: can you check if its the spacing issue

Comment: Means what ? Where do you think the space is missing ?

Comment: Try using ng-class https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: `someCssclassName {{dummyclass.textProp}}`